# Add class jQuery does not work

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery

```
$(function(){
$(".img-fulltext-left img").addClass("art-lightbox");
});
```

to add "art-lightbox" class to ".img-fulltext-left" images. But on my site - http://www.podivejte.cz/vinarstvi/akce-detail/93-movie-show.html - this do not work when I have enabled JE Slide Down Menu.

There is probably some jQuery conflict. Can anybody help?

Many thanks!

Sorky

Comment: can you show us issue on jsfiddle or jsbin?  and show the problem?

Comment: I can not do it because this problem is probably caused JE Slide Down Menu. When I turn it off it works great.

Comment: @user2332117 in that case try to add an "!important" to .art-lightbox in you css

Comment: No, problem is that jQuery do not add "art-lightbox" class to image tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
$("img.img-fulltext-left").addClass("art-lightbox");
});
```

I think you want to add the class `art-lightbox` to `img` having class `img-fulltext-left`

`$("img.img-fulltext-left")` will select all `img` with the class `img-fulltext-left`

Let me know if i got you wrong

Comment: I wan to add class "art-lightbox" to img which is inside div with class "img-fulltext-left". There is probably some conflict with another jquery, becasue when I disable JE Slide Down Menu everythink goes right.